# Google Play Games ask for sign in, after successful sign in

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I implemented Google Play Games sign in in my app, and it works.

But I have problem when I try to use app in offline mode, without Internet connection, because it ask me again to sign in.

It seems like sign in session expired or something like that, because this happens 30 minutes or 1 hour after successful sign in.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainMenuFragment.Listener,  

GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,  
GameFragment.Listener, ResultFragment.Listener {

//Fragments
MainMenuFragment mMainFragment;
GameFragment mGameFragment;
ResultFragment mResultFragment;

// Client used to interact with Google APIs
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

// Are we currently resolving a connection failure?
private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;

// Has the user clicked the sign-in button?
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

// Automatically start the sign-in flow when the Activity starts
private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;

// request codes we use when invoking an external activity
private static final int RC_RESOLVE = 5000;
private static final int RC_UNUSED = 5001;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

//Debug
private String TAG = "IGRA";

//Shared Preferences stuff
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "TheButtonChallenge";
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set activity to be the full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the Google API Client with access to Plus and Games
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();

    Log.d(TAG, "activity on created");

    //Fragments
    mMainFragment = new MainMenuFragment();
    mGameFragment = new GameFragment();
    mResultFragment = new ResultFragment();

    // listen to fragment events
    mMainFragment.setListener(this);
    mGameFragment.setListener(this);
    mResultFragment.setListener(this);

    // add initial fragment (welcome fragment)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "activity on created savedInstanceState");

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mMainFragment).commit();
    }

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = mPrefs.edit();
}



// Switch UI to the given fragment
void switchToFragment(Fragment newFrag) {
    Log.d(TAG, "switch fragment");

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, newFrag)
               .commitAllowingStateLoss();

}

private boolean isSignedIn() {
    return (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!isSignedIn()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart(): connecting");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    else{

    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop(): disconnecting");
    /*if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onStartGameRequested() {
    Log.d(TAG, "new game");
    startGame();
}

@Override
public void onShowAchievementsRequested() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(this, getString(R.string.achievements_not_available)).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onShowLeaderboardsRequested() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(this, getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available)).show();
    }

}

@Override
public int getHighScore() {
    return mPrefs.getInt("highScore", 0);
}


void startGame(){
    switchToFragment(mGameFragment);
}

public void onEnteredScore(int finalScore){

    mResultFragment.setFinalScore(finalScore);

    // push those accomplishments to the cloud, if signed in
    pushAccomplishments(finalScore);

    // check for achievements
    checkForAchievements(finalScore);

    // switch to the exciting "you won" screen
    switchToFragment(mResultFragment);
}

/**
 * Check for achievements and unlock the appropriate ones.
 *
 * @param finalScore the score the user got.
 */
void checkForAchievements(int finalScore) {

    int playCounter = mPrefs.getInt("playCounter", 0);
    int highScore = mPrefs.getInt("highScore", 0);
    playCounter++;

    Log.d("FINAL SCORE:" , String.valueOf(finalScore));
    Log.d("HIGH SCORE: ", String.valueOf(highScore));

    editor.putInt("playCounter", playCounter);
    editor.commit();

    if(finalScore>highScore){
        editor.putInt("highScore", finalScore);
        editor.commit();
        mResultFragment.setHighScore(finalScore);
    }

    if(playCounter == 1){
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_first_time_play));

    }
    // Check if each condition is met; if so, unlock the corresponding
    // achievement.
    if (finalScore >= 50) {
        //achievementToast(getString(R.string.achievement_arrogant_toast_text));
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_win_50_points));
    }
    if (finalScore >= 80) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_win_80_points));
    }
    if (finalScore >= 100) {
       // achievementToast(getString(R.string.achievement_leet_toast_text));
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_win_100_points));
    }
    if(finalScore >= 150){
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_win_150_points));
    }
    if(finalScore >= 200){
        Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_win_200_points));
    }
}

void achievementToast(String achievement) {
    // Only show toast if not signed in. If signed in, the standard Google Play
    // toasts will appear, so we don't need to show our own.
    if (!isSignedIn()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.achievement) + ": " + achievement,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void pushAccomplishments(int finalScore) {

    if (!isSignedIn()) {
        // can't push to the cloud, so save locally
       // mOutbox.saveLocal(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "can't push to the cloud, so save locally");
        return;
    }
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),
            finalScore);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected(): connected to Google APIs");
    // Show sign-out button on main menu
    //mMainFragment.setShowSignInButton(false);

    // Show "you are signed in" message on win screen, with no sign in button.
    //mWinFragment.setShowSignInButton(false);

    // Set the greeting appropriately on main menu
    Player p = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);

    String displayName;
    if (p == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "mGamesClient.getCurrentPlayer() is NULL!");
        displayName = "???";
    } else {
        displayName = p.getDisplayName();
        Log.d(TAG, displayName);
    }
    mMainFragment.setGreeting("Hello, " + displayName);


    // if we have accomplishments to push, push them
    /*if (!mOutbox.isEmpty()) {
        pushAccomplishments();
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.your_progress_will_be_uploaded),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onWinScreenDismissed() {
    switchToFragment(mGameFragment);
}

@Override
public void onWinScreenSignInClicked() {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this, requestCode, resultCode,
                    R.string.signin_failure, R.string.signin_other_error);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended(): attempting to connect");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): attempting to resolve");
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed(): already resolving");
        return;
    }

    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;
       // if (Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
        //}
        //else{
           // Log.d("IGRA", "Nema Interenta");
      //  }
    }

    // Sign-in failed, so show sign-in button on main menu
    mMainFragment.setGreeting(getString(R.string.signed_out_greeting));
    //mMainMenuFragment.setShowSignInButton(true);
   // mWinFragment.setShowSignInButton(true);
}
```

Comment: Sign in does expire, but it should silently reauthorize.  Can you clarify exactly what is happening?  Are you getting `onConnectionFailed()` when you don't expect to?

Comment: Yes, if don't use app for like 1 hour and then I open app and get onConnectionFaield(), so after that sign in dialog appears.

Comment: I would put break points everywhere you are calling mGoogleApiClient.connect() and see if it is you that is triggering the login. OnConnectionFailed will get called as a result of calling mGoogleApiClient.connect(), I believe.